# GRM tools equivalent AU plugin set?

Tags: sound-design, plugin, pro-tools, gameaudio, logic

Can anyone recommend me a AU equivalent for Pro Tools GRM tools plugin pack? I´ve swiched from pro tools to logic and would like to have similar FX plugins in my productions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Grm tools v3 work as Rtas, Vst and AU: they just work in Logic! BTW, just updated to v3.2

They're quite unique, but there are other interesting plugins to try: have a look at Michael Norris' SoundMagic Spectral suite http://www.michaelnorris.info/software/soundmagic-spectral.html

Best
Davide